# R Forecasting with STL

Tags: r, stl, forecasting

I am using Rob Hyndman [forecasting with STL](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecast3/)

```
fit <- stl(USAccDeaths,s.window="periodic")
forecast(fit)
```

I am trying to get forecasted numbers (don't want to plot), so I just used `forecast(fit)`, but I couldn't find source for `forecast()`, there are lot of `forecast` functions in [forecast package](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/tree/master/R) source files. I need to understand how these numbers are calculated to match with other implementation I have.

Can someone please help me in pointing to which part of the code will be executed? That helps me in continuing my debugging.

**EDIT:**

My current understanding is, `forecast.R --->forecast.ts` will be called and from there

```
stlf(object,h=h,level=level,fan=fan,lambda = lambda, ...)
```

should be invoked. Am I correct? If so, where is the source for `stlf` function located?

Comment: The 'fit'-object should have a class, and the `forecast` function is probably generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that is correct. If you run the example in `?forecast` which is what you are showing, then the 'fit'-object is of class-"stl" and so `forecast.stl` is the underlying function that is called.

`stlf` is in the namespace of pkg:forecast. Just type the function name (without quotes) at the console.

Comment: Thanks you. It seems this source is in Season.R file.